# Is it possible to change color of elevation of widget in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've dig into the classes of Card widget, can't find the parameter controlling the color of the elevation.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean the color of the shadow caused by elevation? If so, AFAIK, Compose UI uses system elevation for that, and AFAIK we have no means of controlling the color of that.

Comment: @CommonsWare 
Sorry mate, I'm not an English native speaker. What does AFAIK means?
But yeah, I get what you mean. Just curiosity.

Comment: AFAIK means "As far as I know."